# @SchedulerLock integration tests fail

Tags: spring, spring-boot, scheduled-tasks, junit5, schedule

I have added `@SchedulerLock` to an existing `@Scheduled` Task. Now my integration tests fail. I have added following dependecies for SchedulerLock:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>net.javacrumbs.shedlock</groupId>
  <artifactId>shedlock-spring</artifactId>
  <version>5.11.0</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>net.javacrumbs.shedlock</groupId>
  <artifactId>shedlock-provider-jdbc-template</artifactId>
  <version>5.11.0</version>
</dependency>
```

In my `ScheduleService` i have multiple autowired services which i need to use. E.g. like this:

```
SomeService someService;

@Scheduled(cron = "0 0 3 * * ?")
@SchedulerLock(name = "StatisticService_processStatisticsAtThreeAM", lockAtLeastFor = "PT10M")
void methodToSchedule() {
 someService.method();
}
```

Running my previously working integration tests now result in an exception:
`Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "package.to.service.SomeService .method()" because "this.someService" is null`

My Integrationtest is setup like this:

```
@ActiveProfiles("test")
@ExtendWith(SpringExtension.class)
@SpringBootTest
@AutoConfigureMockMvc
@WithMockUser
@Transactional
public class MyTest {

@Autowired ScheduleService service;
/* tests */ 
}
```

PS: The application itself is running and the locks are correctly put into my database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it by calling the method from another service:

```
public class ScheduleService {

SomeService someService;

// originally called with Scheduling
void methodToSchedule() {
  someService.method();
 }
}
```

---

```
public class Schedulerr {
  ScheduleService service;
  void newScheduleMethod() {
    service.methodToSchedule();
  }
}
```